# Trying to add 5 years using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to add up to 5 years and each year it adds I am storing it to be displayed later.

```js
const myDate = moment("2021-07-28", "YYYY-MM-DD");
const valid = myDate.isValid();

const addYear1 = myDate.add(1, 'y');
const firstYear = addYear1;
const addYear2 = firstYear.add(1, 'y');
const addYear3 = addYear2.add(1, 'y');
const addYear4 = addYear3.add(1, 'y');
const addYear5 = addYear4.add(1, 'y');

console.log("Year:", myDate);
console.log("is Year Valid:", valid);
console.log("Adding year1:", addYear1);
console.log("Adding year2:", addYear2);
console.log("Adding year3:", addYear3);
console.log("Adding year4:", addYear4);
console.log("Adding year5:", addYear5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The output ends up being 2026 for all the outputs. I  expecting to be:

```
Year: 2021
Adding year1: 2022
Adding year2: 2023
Adding year3: 2024
Adding year4: 2025
Adding year5: 2026
```

Comment: `add` *Mutates the original moment by adding time* (https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/). Each time you add you're not doing so in isolation, you're using the same object. All of your consts hold references to the same moment object.

Comment: @BrianThompson, seems like you're 90% of the way to an answer. It should be down there.

Comment: Fair enough. Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const addYear1 = myDate.add(1,'y').format('YYYY'); // 2022
const addYear2 = myDate.add(1, 'y').format('YYYY'); // 2023
const addYear3 = myDate.add(1, 'y').format('YYYY'); // 2024
const addYear4 = myDate.add(1, 'y').format('YYYY'); // 2025
const addYear5 = myDate.add(1, 'y').format('YYYY'); // 2026
```

Just re-use the original moment object and modify it each time you want to use it.

Comment: Note: this works because `format` is returning strings evaluated at each line. This is a perfectly valid solution, and I'm sure much more efficient than `cloning` 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using moment but using vanilla js you can use this

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toString())
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1)
console.log(date.toString())
```

You can pass any string inside Date() to set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

`add` *Mutates the original moment by adding time* ([docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/)).

Each time you add you're not doing so in isolation, you're using the same object. All of your `const`s hold references to the same moment object.

To make a real copy of the moment object, you'd need to use [`clone`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/12-moment-clone/):

```
const firstYear = addYear1;
// to 
const firstYear = addYear1.clone();
```

Your final result could be something like this:

```
const addYear2 = firstYear.clone().add(1, 'y');
const addYear3 = addYear2.clone().add(1, 'y');
const addYear4 = addYear3.clone().add(1, 'y');
const addYear5 = addYear4.clone().add(1, 'y');
```

Or just using the same base object and adding different years:

```
const myDate = moment("2021-07-28", "YYYY-MM-DD");
const addYear2 = myDate.clone().add(2, 'y');
const addYear3 = myDate.clone().add(3, 'y');
const addYear4 = myDate.clone().add(4, 'y');
const addYear5 = myDate.clone().add(5, 'y');
```

Also see [this related issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/955).